# what is the difference(benifits) between using sling model and Model creating using WCMUSE?

Tags: aem, sightly, sling-models, htl

What is the difference between creating

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class MyModel {  }
```

and

```
public class MyModel extends WCMUsePojo { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty well covered in the [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html#picking-the-best-use-provider-for-a-project) and the main advantages are:

- convenient injection annotations for data retrieval
- easy to extend from other Sling Models
- simple setup for unit testing

The drawback highlighted in the documentation (*lacks flexibility in terms of component overlaying, relying on service.ranking configurations*) is being tackled by [SLING-5992](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5992) which allows mapping a certain model implementation to a resource type.